# Android NavDeepLinkBuilder's setArguments set null instead of bundle

Tags: android, navigation, arguments, deep-linking

I have this config for push notification

```
NavDeepLinkBuilder(context)
    .setComponentName(SplashActivity::class.java)
    .setGraph(R.navigation.navigation)
    .setDestination(R.id.nav_settings)
    .setArguments(bundleOf("key" to "value"))
    .createPendingIntent()
```

but when I wanna log it

```
intent.extras?.keySet()?.forEach {
    Log.d("QQQ", "SplashActivity.intent.extras.item: " + it + " - " + intent.extras?.getString(it))
}
```

i got this:

```
SplashActivity.intent.extras.item: android-support-nav:controller:deepLinkExtras - null
SplashActivity.intent.extras.item: android-support-nav:controller:deepLinkIntent - null
SplashActivity.intent.extras.item: android-support-nav:controller:deepLinkIds - null
SplashActivity.intent.extras.item: android-support-nav:controller:deepLinkArgs - null
```

When I'm using this and set parameter for intent's bundle then it's working (under API 29, on 31 this solution is crashing)

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0)
```

Comment: The extras are sent to your `R.id.nav_settings` - that's where you'd log them, they aren't something you are supposed to be reading in the activity.

Comment: The ```setDestination``` can also accept args as a second parameter

*Params:

destId - destination ID to deep link to.

args - Arguments to pass to this destination and any synthetic back stack created due to this destination being added.*


Plus the ```android-support-nav:controller:deepLinkExtras``` appear in the ```extras``` only when I use ```setArguments``` so it's going to component (activity)

Comment: It is going _through_ the activity to the destination. Why aren't you logging them at the destination?

Comment: TaskStackBuilder solved by problem